# Publishing an android studio with database

Tags: android, database

Sorry I'm still a beginner when it comes to Android.
How can I publish an application to the Android Play store and my application is connecting to database.
Is there is a special database from this kind of application or can I work with a WAMP server?

Comment: You can use the WAMP database. It will fail if you have enough user generating enough content that fills it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google play does'nt restrict the use of any database , you can use whatever you want

As long as you can make it work for your need there should be no problem submit your app to google play